# my phone hit a pavement and 3g/4g stopped working. next step?

Tags: 3g, htc-desire-z, 4g

As I was cycling, my htc rezound fell on the pavement. The battery popped out.

There are few scratches but no visible damage.

I start the phone and it's fine as long as I don't use data.
Once I use data, the phone uses "1" may be it's ev-do. speedtest shows 129 kbps down rate.

I tried flashing and installing a leaked ICS. that didn't solve the problem.

I would think that the damage was because of the physical shock of hitting the ground (nothing broke). so is there a way to diagnose it? to check if 4g is still working?

Comment: Maybe contact the carrier, they may be able to do some test on the device to see if it is actually able to connect to the 4g network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTC Dream (G1) the UMTS radio (3G) is a separate board from the rest of the phone. While this is a Desire Z and I haven't had the opportunity to take one apart, it's probably very similar.

The 3G/4G daughterboard (or if it's connected, antenna) could have failed, cracked, disconnected or sustained damage in some other way. Software won't fix it. You have damaged hardware.

Comment: is it hard to buy a replacement or my only option is to ship it to htc?

Comment: I am not sure only because I don't know exactly what failed. I'd have to look at the Desire Z teardowns to know for sure.

Comment: http://tjworld.net/blog/htc-desire-z-tear-down Does not seem like there's a separate daughterboard. Ship the phone to HTC.

Comment: The antennas on the Rezound are built into the battery cover.  It could be as simple as a bad contact that could be repaired by replacing the battery cover.